moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::setWorkspace doesnt work for manipulator?
I wrote a node that performs the logic of moving the manipulator. There is a problem that I use the move_group.setWorkspace() method - it doesn’t work in any way. the manipulator calmly moves beyond the boundaries of the designated area.
  manipulator_group->setEndEffectorLink(goal.ee_link);
  manipulator_group->setWorkspace(
      goal.set_workspace.minx, goal.set_workspace.miny, goal.set_workspace.minz,
      goal.set_workspace.maxx, goal.set_workspace.maxy,
      goal.set_workspace.maxz);

What should I do if I need to make sure that the robot does not cross the work area when moving?
